# File with multiple lines read and append to single variable

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I need to read a file with 3 lines

backuplist.txt

/etc/

/home

/boot

and append it to a single variable to  compress it

```
#!/bin/bash

cat backuplist.txt |
{
while read -r line
do
echo $line
/bin/tar -zcf /backup/test.tar.gz $line
done
echo $line
}
```

While running the script the tar file is created only with /boot directory.

Anyway to read 3 lines to 3 different variables and compress it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find you can do that much more easily with:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/tar -zcf /backup/test.tar.gz $(<cat /backuplist.txt)
```

As was, your script was over-writing test.tar.gz for each line in the file.

Comment: Just a nit or two, `$(...)` is much more readable and `$(<backuplist.txt)` removes the UUOc (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`).

Comment: Good point about the UUOc.  I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: With respect to readability: that's a matter of taste, however.  I don't find one form or the other particularly more readable, and I imagine others prefer seeing backticks.  Finally, though the OP is likely talking about bash, I'm not sure $(< works on many older sh-derived shells.

Comment: Much improved. Like I said they were 'nits', but over the past decade or so there has been a general move to using command substitution with `$(...)` instead of backticks. (they do the same thing -- essentially). As to the use of redirection with command substitution, it's POSIX, so it will work with any shell. (even with backticks `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it like:-

```
#!/bin/bash

file_list=$(cat /backuplist.txt)

/bin/tar -zcf /backup/test.tar.gz $file_list
```